# Upper limit on UIDs and GIDs in AIX

Tags: users, login, aix, uid

What is the upper limit on the UIDs and GIDs in AIX?

Comment: Any particular version in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From AIX 6.1 onwards, UIDs and GIDs are 32 bits in length, and so max out at 4,294,967,295.

See, for example, http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.files/group_security.htm
which describes the group entry.

Earlier versions of AIX only supported 16bit IDs and so maxed out at 65,535.